# drawback of including primary key creation along in the table creation script

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Sample script:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Countries](
    [Id] [nvarchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Countries] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I was told by a DBA that **I should not include the `Primary Key`  constraint in the `table create` script** but I don't really understand.

Could anyone tell me **why** and **what is the best practice** in this situation (*for example: create table first and add primary key later in alter table*)?

Thanks,

Comment: Don't think i matter but I'm not a DBA. What did the DBA tell you the reason was when you asked why?.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: unfortunately the DBA is from another organization, so I could not ask him directly

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he wants to load the table with data and then create the index after. That way index fragmentation and statistics would be in good shape.

With that said a good choice of clustering key would keep fragmentation low during the data load. Kimberly Tripp has written a few [posts](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/) on topic of choosing appropriate clustering keys.